# Drupal 7 five star module services. How to?

Tags: drupal, service, rating, drupal-services

Is there any services module available for drupal five star rating module. I am using services to create product etc,.. But I have searched the internet about drupal five star module services. Is there any module available in drupal with services included?

Comment: How do you want to use the 'services' for fivestar/voting API?

Comment: I want to post vote using service, like vote:50% etc,..

Comment: Fivestar module is based on Voting API. So, instead of looking for something with fivestar, you should check with voting API